# How to determine target when updating android project

Tags: android, build

I'm trying to make my build process as automated as possible. Somtimes I work from different computers.

One one computer if I use the command "android list targets" I get four different targets, with IDs 1-4. On another computer I have only three targets installed so they are IDs 1-3. The problem is that the IDs aren't the same since it's just 1-indexed and counts up.

So if I want to write a script that updates a project and then builds it, how do I do that so that it runs safely on both systems and targets the same sdk? There is no way that I see to pick a target by it's name rather than it's arbitray ID according to android list targets.

Thanks!

Comment: Plus if I ever install other targets, then any script I wrote to target a specfic ID would probably fail too depending on the new order of the targets listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **name** instead of the target's id. For `android list targets`, it's shown for each item, e.g.

```
 id: 1 or "android-15"
     Name: Android 4.0.3
     Type: Platform
```

Using `android-15` works just as well.

Comment: Ugh. I never even bothered trying it since I just read the help and it said -t is the ID so I just kind of assumed it HAD to be the ID. That's annoying, but thank you!